# How to run a long cmd command using psexec?

Tags: cmd, psexec

I am trying to use PsExec to run the following command:
 `net use Z: \\myComputerName\c\ProgramData\directoryA`
to map drive Z on my computer.
It works fine when I run it as is (without psexec before it) on the console.

But it doesn't work with psexec.
Here is the full psexec command line I am running in the console:

```
psexec -i -d \\myComputerName -u userName -p password   
       net use Z: \\Davidpc\c\ProgramData\ESET
```

If I run any other short command like: `calc` or `notepad.exe` or `cmd.exe` etc instead of
"**net use Z: \Davidpc\c\ProgramData\ESET**" it works fine
 (meaning it strats the calculator \ notepad \ console)

How can I make it work using psexec?

Comment: Why do you need psexec to run a local command on your own computer?

Comment: May sound silly, but you did `/Delete` `Z:` before trying to remap it didn't you?

Comment: No. I just tried to run the command as is. And I want to test the command on my own computer before trying to tun it on other computers

Comment: What are you expecting that this will do? The command will be run under your account. Do you think it will be there when you run the next command remotely?

Comment: I am expecting that the command will execute successfully. Meaning that immediately I will see a mapped drive "Z" in my explorer (after clicking twice on my computer icon) , like I do when I run the command without psexec before it as I wrote above in my question